# How to update single column based on values in the next row

Tags: php, sql, amazon-web-services

I have a raw data set that looks like this

```
timestamp   | eventtype    | status    | state      | FinalState | Difference  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
12:00:56 PM | STATE_CHANGE | NULL      | NULL       | NULL       | 00:00:00    |
12:01:39 PM | STATE_CHANGE | Available | CONNECTING | NULL       | 00:00:00    |
```

To perform some reports on the status of the user I need to update FinalState and then calculate the time difference between the even types using the timestamp.

This is the logic that needs to be followed to update FinalState

```
IF currentrow_state == null 
    IF currentrow_status == NULL 
        return available
    ELSE nextrow_status
ELSE IF ( currentrow_state == NULL OR currentrow_state == ENDED)
        IF previousrow_state == currentrow_state 
            return nextrow_status
        ELSE
            return currentrow_state
    ELSE
        return currentrow_state
```

I am confused in how to perform this operation. I think it could be done in a PHP script to run through the entire data but the data is going to be huge and may cause the script to time out to run for hundreds of users.

I thought it would be wise to run this data manipulation inside the DB it self. Currently it is being store in AWS RDS so its in SQL. But I can not figure out how to do it and do not know if that is a good solution.

Any thoughts on how this could be done in the most efficient way ?

**Update**

After following the tip form the comment I got this query partially working. I moved the data to another table with serialnumber

```
SELECT serialnumber,timestamp,username,status,state,
    CASE 
        WHEN state = 'NULL' 
            THEN (CASE 
                        WHEN status = 'NULL' 
                        THEN "Available"
                  ELSE (SELECT status FROM ATEMP WHERE  state IS NULL AND status IS NOT NULL AND serialnumber=1)
                  END) 
            ELSE (CASE 
                        WHEN state = 'NULL' OR state LIKE 'ENDED' 
                        THEN (SELECT status FROM ATEMP WHERE  state IS NULL AND status IS NOT NULL AND serialnumber=1)
                        ELSE state
                        END)
            END as finalvalue
FROM ATEMP;
```

But I am not able to get data from the subquery. Keeps getting (null) as the results. From a few more testing it does not look like the query is returning the  data of status from row2 to row1

Comment: I am confused as to what to try out. Should work with a PHP script first or investigate into DB

Comment: you can try like case when state=null then Select status. from table where serial_number=(serial number+1) as the ongoing case would have a specific serail_number so we dont need to traverse for it just that to increment this serial number to +1 so that next row or -1 previous row will be returned and then using subquery to get status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I upgraded MYSQL to MYSQL 8 and used the two functions `LEAD` and `LAG` and a concept called `WINDOW` which I am still yet to learn about.

And then this query did wonderfully

```
Select * FROM (
SELECT serialnumber,timestamp,username,status,state,
    CASE 
        WHEN state = '' 
            THEN (CASE 
                        WHEN status = '' 
                        THEN "Available"
                  ELSE LEAD(status) over w
                  END) 
            ELSE (CASE 
                        WHEN state = '' OR state LIKE 'ENDED' 
                        THEN (CASE 
                                    WHEN state = LAG(state) over w
                                    THEN LEAD(status) over w
                                    ELSE state
                                END) 
                        ELSE state
                        END)
            END as FinalState
FROM ATEMP window w as (order by serialnumber)) a order by timestamp,FinalState DESC ;
```

Hope this helps any one looking for a similar function.

MYSQL link here

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE 
               WHEN STATE IS NULL
                 THEN 
                (
               CASE WHEN STATUS=NULL
                THEN "AVAILABLE"
                ELSE
                (SELECT STATUS FROM TABLE WHERE  STATE
                 IS NULL AND STATUS IS NOT NULL AND 
                   ROWNUM=1)
               END CASE  )

               WHEN STATE IS NULL OR STATUS LIKE 
              "ENDED" THEN

                 (
               CASE WHEN
                  STATE= (SELECT STATE FROM TABLE 
                   WHERE  ROWNUM=ROWNUM-1)
                   THEN 
                                     STATE

             )
                ELSE
                (SELECT STATUS FROM TABLE WHERE  STATE
                 IS NULL AND STATUS IS NOT NULL AND 
                   ROWNUM=1)
               END CASE  )

     )
     ELSE 
            (SELECT STATE FROM TABLE WHERE  STATE
                 IS NULL AND STATUS IS NOT NULL AND 
                   ROWNUM=1)
         END CASE FROM TABLE;
```

You can work around with setting case for each ifs as I cant completely figure out to identify the next row or previous row state/status based on your columns as identifier in subquery. Can try the above as a template.

Comment: Interesting notion.. using a query inside a query and using the row number as identifier to jump to the previous or next row. Going to try this out. Thank you